Execute after ajax is complete -- without accessing the ajax function?
I need to perform a JS function after an ajax function is complete (filtering posts in WordPress). However, the ajax filter tool is created by a WordPress plugin that I can't edit. How can I detect that a particular ajax call has finished when I didn't create the ajax function?
For example (I know this isn't correct, but trying to show what I want to do):
  $(document).on("AJAX HAS FINISHED", function(){
        console.log("ajax complete");
        activatePopup();
  });

Can this be done?

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/trigger-a-custom-js-function-after-filtering/. The short answer is "yes, you can edit the plugin"

I wouldn't want to edit the plugin, as it would be overwritten at their next update.

jQuery has an ajaxComplete event you could use.
So, something like this
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    console.log("AJAX request completed");
    // Check if AJAX request was for filtering posts
    if (settings.url.includes("your-ajax-endpoint-url")) {
        // your desired logic + ajax complete
        activatePopup();
    }
});

